# BeautifulSoup : Terminal output are in different lines

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want that the all the beautiful soup output should be in one line rather in a newline

HTML:

```
<h1 class="page-title nosp" data-price-promise-enabled="">
    <span>SAMSUNG</span>
    <span>QE43Q60RATXXU 43" Smart 4K Ultra HD HDR QLED TV with Bixby</span>
</h1>
```

Code:

```
try:
    title = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class':'page-title nosp'}).text

except:
    title = None
```

Terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\Zandrio> & C:/Users/Zandrio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Advanced Project/Proxy/currys.py"
SAMSUNG
QE43Q60RATXXU 43" Smart 4K Ultra HD HDR QLED TV with Bixby
```

I want output without a whitespace or newline

```
SAMSUNG QE43Q60RATXXU 43" Smart 4K Ultra HD HDR QLED TV with Bixby
```

Comment: I think you need this: ```print("%s %s" % (title.find("span").text, title.find("span").find_next("span").text))```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? As an aside, don’t use a bare `except` statement like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
print(title.strip().replace('\n',' '))
```